# Output to one of two files after if statement evaluation

Tags: python, output, python-3.5

I am using the python nmap module to do certificate discovery and monitoring.

```
import nmap
import time
import datetime
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
from datetime import date
import itertools
```

This is the function that manages the nmap scan.

```
SSLmonitor = nmap.PortScanner()
def SSLmon(IPaddress):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    filename = now.strftime("/results/%Y-%m-%dSSLmonWeekly.txt", "r")
    filename2 = now.strftime("/results/%Y-%m-%dSSLmonWeeklyExpiring.txt", "r")
    results = SSLmonitor.scan(hosts=IPaddress, arguments='--script=ssl-cert -p 443')
    # If statement checks to see if last scanned address has ['scan'].
    #print(results.keys())
    if 'scan' in results:
        hosts = results['scan']
        #print(hosts)
    # If host had cert on 443 try, else do pass.
    try:
        for host in hosts: # Chunk through the tuple.
            try:
                # Get the information for each host in the tuple
                cert = hosts[host]['tcp'][443]['script']['ssl-cert']
                try:
    for host in hosts: # Chunk through the dictionary to get the key value pairs we want.
        try:
            # Get the information for each host in the hecka-dictionary.
            cert = hosts[host]['tcp'][443]['script']['ssl-cert']
            cert2 = cert.replace('Not valid after:  ', '~')
            indexed = cert2.index('~')
                if datetime.date(int(cert2[indexed+1:indexed+5]), int(cert2[indexed+6:indexed+8]), int(cert2[indexed+9:indexed+11])) - datetime.date.today()
                    with open(filename, 'a') as f:
                        with redirect_stdout(f):
                            print("\n", IPaddress, cert.replace(':', '=').replace('commonName=', '\ncommonName=').replace('/', '\n'))
                else:
                    with open(filename2, 'a') as e:
                        with redirect_stdout(e):
                            print("\n", IPaddress, cert.replace(':', '=').replace('commonName=', '\ncommonName=').replace('/', '\n'))
            except Exception:
                pass
    except Exception:
        pass
```

I looping through a list of IP addresses I know have certs
on port 443, and running them through the scanner.

```
#--------------------------------------------------------------
# Iterate through list of hosts with discovered certs
#--------------------------------------------------------------
with open("/weeklyscanlist/DiscoveredCertsByIP.txt", "r") as text_file:
    for line in itertools.islice(text_file, 1, 4250):
        SSLmon(str(line))
```

When I was handling output like this

```
if datetime.date(int(expDate[0]), int(expDate[1]), int(expDate[2])) - datetime.date.today() < datetime.timedelta(days = 30):
    print("\n", IPaddress, cert.replace(':', '=').replace('commonName=', '\ncommonName=').replace('/', '\n'), "this cert is expiring soon)
else:
    print("\n", IPaddress, cert.replace(':', '=').replace('commonName=', '\ncommonName=').replace('/', '\n'), "this cert is good for a while)
```

And it was working fine, so I know it the way I am handling writing the output to a file, but I can't find a way to handle this.
I've also tried

```
    if datetime.date(int(expDate[0]), int(expDate[1]), int(expDate[2])) - datetime.date.today() < datetime.timedelta(days = 30):
        fn = open(filename2, 'a')
        fn.write("\n", IPaddress, cert.replace(':', '=').replace('commonName=', '\ncommonName=').replace('/', '\n'))
        fn.close()
    else:
        f = open(filename, 'a')
        f.write("\n", IPaddress, cert.replace(':', '=').replace('commonName=', '\ncommonName=').replace('/', '\n'))
        f.close()
```

without success.

Comment: can you post your stacktrace?

Comment: f.write takes only one argument...try formatting it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you should do, following up on deweyredman’s sage advice to use string formatting:

1. Use string formatting to generate the output line of the file
2. Use an if-then to pick the filename
3. Only use one file write block to stay DRY

   ```
   dt_diff = datetime.date(int(expDate[0]), int(expDate[1]), int(expDate[2])) - datetime.date.today()
   which_filename = filename if  dt_diff < datetime.timedelta(days = 30) else filename2
   with open(which_filename, 'a') as f:
       line = '\n%s %s' % (
           IPaddress, 
           cert.replace(':', '='
           ).replace('commonName=', '\ncommonName='
           ).replace('/', '\n'),)
       f.write(line)
   ```

Comment: I had a huge issue with the code I posted above, as in it was an outdate version of the script when I had been passing a much different nmap argument. So if anyone was using it and scratching their head as to why the key value pairs in the tuple were so different, thats why. I apologize. Also that being said this was the solution, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your args to f.write are incorrect...try:

```
if datetime.date(int(expDate[0]), int(expDate[1]), int(expDate[2])) - datetime.date.today() < datetime.timedelta(days = 30):
    fn = open(filename2, 'a')
    fn.write("{} {} {}".format("\n", IPaddress, cert.replace(':', '=').replace('commonName=', '\ncommonName=').replace('/', '\n')))
    fn.close()
else:
    f = open(filename, 'a')
    f.write("{} {} {}".format("\n", IPaddress, cert.replace(':', '=').replace('commonName=', '\ncommonName=').replace('/', '\n')))
    f.close()
```

f.write takes one argument...you're passing it three.